# How to wrap all html responses in a html layout using apache 2.2?

Tags: apache-2.2, html

I have multiple web-apps running on a server using different technologies.

- java
- php (wordpress)
- python (trac)

They are all front-ended with Apache 2.2.  My question is does anyone know a good way to wrap all these web apps with a common template (header/footer).

I was looking into mod_layout, but the documentation is quite limited and I was unable to get even the simplest example to work.

I also looked at mod_include, but I'm not sure if that is a good idea.

Comment: I just got a simple example of mod_layout working, the problem was mod deflate had to be disabled

Comment: One more thing that I figured out is that if you want your header/footers to be java servlets then you need to use mod_jk and JkEnvVar to pase the mod_layout environment variables. 

 - http://www.musc.edu/webserver/mod_layout.html#_1_15
 - http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/apache.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force all pages of a certain extension to include a header and footer by setting it out in the `httpd.conf` of the server, or just in the `.htaccess` of each particular directory/site with the append and prepend directives like so:

```
<FilesMatch "\.html$">
php_value auto_prepend_file /path/to/header.html
php_value auto_append_file /path/to/footer.html
</FilesMatch>
```

The above will match `.html` pages and will force include `/path/to/header.html` before the page content as well as `/path/to/footer.html` after the page.

Just remove the `FilesMatch` lines if you want to force it on all pages.